# What is an "inheritance based proxy" in Spring

Tags: java, spring

When I was going through spring core [related document](http://mylearn.vmware.com/descriptions/Pivotal_EDU_CoreSpring_Datasheet.pdf), I came across concept called "Inheritance based proxies". 
Can anyone please explain a bit on this. It will be nice if you can show some 
code samples. 
Thanks

Comment: It'd also be nice if you pointed us to the part of the docs which talks about this.

Comment: It's in there data sheet for Spring-core course module, linked added to question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of proxies available in Spring:

JDK proxy, which comes out of the box in JDK and CGLib, which is created by the CGLib library (3rd party dependency).

JDK Proxy only works with beans that implement an interface and it is also the Spring recommended way of using AOP.

However, there are lots of scenarios out there where you would have to code concrete classes and therefore must use CGLib. CGLIB proxying works by generating a subclass of the target class at runtime. Spring configures this generated subclass to delegate method calls to the original target: the subclass is used to implement the Decorator pattern, weaving in the advice.

I think that's what is being referred to as '**inheritance based proxy**'. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-api-proxying-class